# Toggle Switch change label text and return boolean Angular 11 bootstrap

Tags: angular, switch-statement, label, toggle

I want to change the status of several toggle-switches on my website to yes or no on a modern way.

I didnt find a ready to use solution, so I have to figure out how to make it correctly in Angular.

I have 10 switches, that have to give back a seperate boolean and change their text to "yes" or "no" individually.  How to achieve this in Angular?

This is my current code, which works for 1 switch. (Using bootstrap 5 in Angular 11)

```
   <div class="form-check form-switch">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" (change)="isTrue()" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
      <label *ngIf="isTrue()" class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Yes</label>
      <label *ngIf="isFalse()" class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">No</label>
    </div>
```

.ts

```
export class SComponent implements OnInit {

  status = true;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  isTrue() {
    return this.status = !this.status;
  }

  isFalse() {
    return this.status === false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Use an array instead?

Answer (score 2):

you can create switch-toggle component and import it in your ShareModule

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, TemplateRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "switch-toggle",
    templateUrl: "./switch-toggle.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./switch-toggle.component.scss"]
})
export class SwitchToggleComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id?: string;
  @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  value: boolean;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
  
    setValue(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.onChange.emit({id: this.id, value: this.value});
    }
}
```

```html
<label class="switch" [ngClass]="{active: value}">
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="id" (change)="setValue(e.target.checked)">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

and use it in your component

```
<switch-toggle [id]="'test1'" (onChange)="doFunction($event)"></switch-toggle>
```

each time you change switch get object like {id: 'test1', value: true or false}

Comment: I don´t get this running, am still a beginner in Angular. It shows different errors:  "error TS7006: Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type."  I´m not using a shared module yet. In my html the doFunction thing is red. Could you give me an explicit example with using my code without using shared module please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggleswitch-cm?file=src/app/app.component.ts
check this link i hope help you